# Shortening css3 animation keyframe definitions

Tags: css, webkit, keyframe

While I was writing many **quasi-identical CSS3 animations**, I wondered if there's a way to shorten the code.
Each time, **only the final keyframe is different**.

```
@-webkit-keyframes one {
    from {
        [identical properties]
    }
    [...etc...]
    80% {
        [identical properties]
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes two {
    from {
        [identical properties]
    }
    [...etc...]
    80% {
        [identical properties]
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
}
```

That code is pretty **long** so I thought it could **be easily shortened** but looks like you have to define the whole animation over and over.
I tried something like this, but that doesn't work in Chrome and Safari.

```
@-webkit-keyframes one, two {
    from {
        [identical properties]
    }
    [...etc...]
    80% {
        [identical properties]
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes two {
    to {
        margin-left: 50px;
    }
}
```

Is there no way to define 2 identical animations? :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid copy-pasting during development, you can use a CSS preprocessor, such as [SCSS / SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). The [mixin feature](http://lesscss.org/#-mixins) greatly reduces the code size:

For a single property, writing a single mixin is sufficient:

```
.Duplicates(@marginLeft) {
    from { /* ... */ }
    80%  { /* ... */ }
    to { margin-left: @marginLeft;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes one {
    .Duplicates(20px);
}
@-webkit-keyframes two {
    .Duplicates(50px);
}
```

### Demo: An animated busy supermarket, using pure CSS(3)

For me, the previous *mixin* was **not sufficient**. I *also* wanted dynamic names and vendor-prefixes <sup>[how?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11028622/938089?sign-and-variables-in-css-keyframes-using-less-css)</sup>, so that I do not have to write a rule 10 x 5 = 50 times (10 names, 5 vendors). That's a chance to show the power of a CSS preprocessor:

- Input (less) - http://pastebin.com/BcRYzdBj - 3kB
- Output (css) - http://pastebin.com/zLCS2z7L - 14kB (Gzipped 999 bytes)
- Demo ([source](http://jsfiddle.net/ecPWA/)): http://jsfiddle.net/ecPWA/show/

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment. Remember that if you are gzipping your CSS that a lot of this inefficiency will disappear.

Comment: Ok, hopefully such possibilities will be implemented on next versions. :)

What do you mean by "gripping my css" ?

Comment: Ooops - Lion autocorrect casualty number one! Should have said gzipping.

Answer (score 1):

Not inherently. Especially with vendor prefixes, CSS can get really dizzying, however if you are deploying the file properly (GZip, caching, etc.) it's not really an inefficiency, just a pain in the butt to write.

Depending on your project, you can [parse CSS as PHP](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/supercharge-your-css-with-php-under-the-hood/#cssvariablecontroversy) and define variables there. I find the idea really sexy but haven't had *enough* of a need to use it.