# Use less to generate dynamic CSS rules based on parameter value and passed mixin

Tags: less

It is possible to achieve something like this in LESS?

```
.some-button(@className) {
  @className { .actionIcon; }
  tr:hover {
    @className { .actionButton; }
  }
}
```

When I call it:

```
.some-button(.edit-action);
```

The expected output should be :

```
.edit-action { .actionIcon; }
tr:hover { .edit-action { .actionButton; } }
```

Currently I'm getting this "Unrecognized input in @className { .actionIcon; }" error:

```
.some-button(@className) {
  @className { .actionIcon; }
  tr:hover {
```

## EDIT

Another thing I would like to achieve is to use a mixin as mixin parameter:

```
.actionButton(@buttonClassName; @buttonType) {
  @{buttonClassName} { 
    .actionIcon; 
  }
  tr:hover {
    @{buttonClassName} { 
        .actionHoverIcon; 
        @buttonType();
    }
  }
}
```

and call is like this:

```
.actionButton(~'.row-edit', button-harmful);
```

where **button-harmful** is a mixin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They call this ["Selector Interpolation"](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-selectors), the correct syntax is:

```
.some-button(@className) {
    @{className} { 
        /* ... */
    }
}

// usage:
.some-button(~'.edit-action');
```

Or alternatively (if you know you will use only classes, i.e. `.` prefixed selectors) like this:

```
.some-button(@className) {
    .@{className} {
        /* ... */
    }
}

// usage:
.some-button(edit-action);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Now I have updated the question to use mixins.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question (i.e. "use a mixin as mixin parameter"): in short, currently this is impossible in a straight forward way. There're a few workarounds that simulate this functionality though (You'll find a brief of those methods [here](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1569) and [here](https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/1648#issuecomment-33861048)).

For example:

```
.actionButton(@buttonClassName, @buttonType) {
    @{buttonClassName} {
        .actionIcon;
    }
    tr:hover {
        @{buttonClassName} {
            .actionHoverIcon;
            .call(@buttonType);
        }
    }
}

// usage:

.call(button-harmful) {.button-harmful}
.actionButton(~'.row-edit', button-harmful);
```

Comment: Btw., I recall I saw a great detailed answer about the "tagged callbacks" technique (e.g. "callback dispatching based on the pattern-matching") here at SO but I can't find it right now (@ScottS - probably it was yours?)

Comment: You are probably thinking of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551313/less-css-pass-mixin-as-a-parameter-to-another-mixin/11589227#11589227)?

Comment: @ScottS I'm not sure. May be, may be not :)