# Less mixin variable call mixin

Tags: less

I have this very simple example as you can see:

```
.large{
  color: blue;
}

.a(@va){
  .large;
  ~".@{va}()";
}


a{
.a(large)
}
```

I keep trying to get the `.large()` or `.large;` to work by calling the `.large` mixin. I keep getting error:

```
Parse error: Unrecognised input
  .large;  ~".@{va}()";}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a mixin by its name stored in a variable. You can achieve the goal by wrapping mixin call into ["detached ruleset"](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) though, e.g.:

```
.large {
    color: blue;
}

.a(@va) {
    @va();
}


a {
    .a({.large})
}
```

There're [other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21609893/2712740) of doing similar things (might be more useful/suitable depending on a use-case).