# CSS Keyframe animations for all browsers?

Tags: css, less

I have a swing animation that I would like to work on all (modern) browser. Do I have the correct css?

Also, what are the other browsers equivalent for: -webkit-transform-origin:top;

also, is there an easier way to write this out, seems like a lot of code? Im using less.

```
.bow{   
    -webkit-animation: swing 3s infinite ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation:    swing 3s infinite ease-in-out;
    -o-animation:      swing 3s infinite ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:    swing 3s infinite ease-in-out; 
    animation:         swing 3s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes swing{
    0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-webkit-transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}

@-moz-keyframes swing{
    0%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-moz-transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{-moz-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}

@-o-keyframes swing {
    0%{-o-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-o-transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{-o-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}

@-ms-keyframes swing {
    0%{-ms-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{-ms-transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{-ms-transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}

@keyframes swing {
    0%{transform:rotate(-3deg)}
    50%{transform:rotate(3deg)}
    100%{transform:rotate(-3deg)}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for animation use can use:

```
.animation(@value){
    -webkit-animation: @value;
    -moz-animation:    @value;
    -o-animation:      @value;
    -ms-transition:    @value;
    animation:         @value;
}

.test{
  .animation(swing 3s infinite ease-in-out);
}

.test1{
  .animation(~"swing 3s infinite, swing 3s infinite");
}
```

for the keyframes in Less, it's kind of strange: 
[How to set keyframes name in LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974128/how-to-set-keyframes-name-in-less)

Answer (score 2):

> I have a swing animation that I would like to work on all (modern) browser. Do I have the correct css?

This question does not fit SO... just prepare a Fiddle, try it yourself, and IF it does not work, come back asking WHY it does not work. Don't post code asking IF it works.

> Also, what are the other browsers equivalent for: `-webkit-transform-origin:top`;

- `transform-origin`
- `-ms-transform-origin`

> also, is there an easier way to write this out, seems like a lot of code? Im using less.

You can generate prefixed code on-the-fly with [Prefix Free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/), or at compile time with [Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/), but since you are using LESS, take a look at [LESS Prefixer](http://lessprefixer.com/).