# CSS animation does not work on Firefox and IE

Tags: php, html, css, firefox, animation

I got this code running perfectly on Chrome and Safari, but it does not work on FF and IE, I tried to solve this problem for couple of hours but still not a clue.

```
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
8% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
}
25% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(3deg);
}
100% { opacity: 0 }
```

}
[Here is the full code](http://jsfiddle.net/bVu9h/)

Comment: What kind of animation are we suppose to see? The fiddle looks rather static to me in both Chrome and Mozilla.Also, not all the vendor-prefixed css is the same. For instance, `-webkit-keyframes` starts with `opacity:1` and `-moz-keyframes` starts with `opacity:0`. By the way, you really shouldn't put all the HTML and the CSS together in the CSS box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the css you made. 
If you are using

```
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation
```

change your

```
-webkit-animation-timing-function
```

to

```
-o-animation-timing-function
```

notice the prefixes.
do the same to other keyframes you made.

Please check http://caniuse.com/css-animation for browser compatibility.
Also check [CSS Keyframe animations for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518670/css-keyframe-animations-for-all-browsers)
for better and simpler syntax.