# Set LESS keyframe name using Web Essentials 2012

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, less, css-animations, web-essentials

I'm trying to create an animating loading spinner in CSS using LESS and I'd like to be able to dynamically set the color of the spinner by setting a class to the element displaying the spinner. I'm using [Web Essentials 2012](http://vswebessentials.com/) for Visual Studio 2012 for the creation and compilation of LESS files.

I'm new to LESS and can't seem to find a way to add dynamic keyframe names. Consider the following code:

**LESS**:

```
@white: #FFF;

.Spin(@color)
{
    0%, 100%
    {
        box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em 0.2em @color, 2em -2em 0 0em @color, 3em 0em 0 -0.5em @color, 2em 2em 0 -0.5em @color, 0em 3em 0 -0.5em @color, -2em 2em 0 -0.5em @color, -3em 0em 0 -0.5em @color, -2em -2em 0 0em @color;
    }

    12.5%
    {
        box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em 0em @color, 2em -2em 0 0.2em @color, 3em 0em 0 0em @color, 2em 2em 0 -0.5em @color, 0em 3em 0 -0.5em @color, -2em 2em 0 -0.5em @color, -3em 0em 0 -0.5em @color, -2em -2em 0 -0.5em @color;
    }

    25%
    {
        box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em -0.5em @color, 2em -2em 0 0em @color, 3em 0em 0 0.2em @color, 2em 2em 0 0em @color, 0em 3em 0 -0.5em @color, -2em 2em 0 -0.5em @color, -3em 0em 0 -0.5em @color, -2em -2em 0 -0.5em @color;
    }

    37.5%
    {
        box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em -0.5em @color, 2em -2em 0 -0.5em @color, 3em 0em 0 0em @color, 2em 2em 0 0.2em @color, 0em 3em 0 0em @color, -2em 2em 0 -0.5em @color, -3em 0em 0 -0.5em @color, -2em -2em 0 -0.5em @color;
    }

    50%
    {
        box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em -0.5em @color, 2em -2em 0 -0.5em @color, 3em 0em 0 -0.5em @color, 2em 2em 0 0em @color, 0em 3em 0 0.2em @color, -2em 2em 0 0em @color, -3em 0em 0 -0.5em @color, -2em -2em 0 -0.5em @color;
    }

    62.5%
    {
        box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em -0.5em @color, 2em -2em 0 -0.5em @color, 3em 0em 0 -0.5em @color, 2em 2em 0 -0.5em @color, 0em 3em 0 0em @color, -2em 2em 0 0.2em @color, -3em 0em 0 0em @color, -2em -2em 0 -0.5em @color;
    }

    75%
    {
        box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em -0.5em @color, 2em -2em 0 -0.5em @color, 3em 0em 0 -0.5em @color, 2em 2em 0 -0.5em @color, 0em 3em 0 -0.5em @color, -2em 2em 0 0em @color, -3em 0em 0 0.2em @color, -2em -2em 0 0em @color;
    }

    87.5%
    {
        box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em 0em @color, 2em -2em 0 -0.5em @color, 3em 0em 0 -0.5em @color, 2em 2em 0 -0.5em @color, 0em 3em 0 -0.5em @color, -2em 2em 0 0em @color, -3em 0em 0 0em @color, -2em -2em 0 0.2em @color;
    }
}

.Keyframes(@name, @color)
{
    @-webkit-keyframes @name { .Spin(@color); }
    @-moz-keyframes @name { .Spin(@color); }
    @-ms-keyframes @name { .Spin(@color); }
    @-o-keyframes @name { .Spin(@color); }
    @keyframes @name { .Spin(@color); }
}

.Animate(@name, @color)
{
    .Keyframes(@name, @color);
    animation: 1.3s linear 0s normal none infinite @name;
    -moz-animation: 1.3s linear 0s normal none infinite @name;
    -o-animation: 1.3s linear 0s normal none infinite @name;
    -webkit-animation: 1.3s linear 0s normal none infinite @name;
}

.loading
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 2.5em;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    cursor: default !important;

    &:before
    {
        border-radius: 50%;
        content: "";
        font-size: 0.2em;
        height: 1em;
        left: 0;
        margin: 5em auto 5em 5em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 1em;
    }

    &.white:before
    {
        .Animate(spinwhite, @white);
    }
}
```

This compiles to the following code:

**CSS (I left out all vendor specific keyframe notations for readability)**:

```
.loading {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 2.5em;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  cursor: default !important;
}
.loading:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  font-size: 0.2em;
  height: 1em;
  left: 0;
  margin: 5em auto 5em 5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1em;
}
.loading.white:before {
  animation: 1.3s linear 0s normal none infinite spinwhite;
  -moz-animation: 1.3s linear 0s normal none infinite spinwhite;
  -o-animation: 1.3s linear 0s normal none infinite spinwhite;
  -webkit-animation: 1.3s linear 0s normal none infinite spinwhite;
}
@keyframes @name {
  0%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em 0.2em #ffffff, 2em -2em 0 0em #ffffff, 3em 0em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 2em 2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 0em 3em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -2em 2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -3em 0em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -2em -2em 0 0em #ffffff;
  }
  12.5% {
    box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em 0em #ffffff, 2em -2em 0 0.2em #ffffff, 3em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, 2em 2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 0em 3em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -2em 2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -3em 0em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -2em -2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff;
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em -0.5em #ffffff, 2em -2em 0 0em #ffffff, 3em 0em 0 0.2em #ffffff, 2em 2em 0 0em #ffffff, 0em 3em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -2em 2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -3em 0em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -2em -2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff;
  }
  37.5% {
    box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em -0.5em #ffffff, 2em -2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 3em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, 2em 2em 0 0.2em #ffffff, 0em 3em 0 0em #ffffff, -2em 2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -3em 0em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -2em -2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff;
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em -0.5em #ffffff, 2em -2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 3em 0em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 2em 2em 0 0em #ffffff, 0em 3em 0 0.2em #ffffff, -2em 2em 0 0em #ffffff, -3em 0em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -2em -2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff;
  }
  62.5% {
    box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em -0.5em #ffffff, 2em -2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 3em 0em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 2em 2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 0em 3em 0 0em #ffffff, -2em 2em 0 0.2em #ffffff, -3em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, -2em -2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff;
  }
  75% {
    box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em -0.5em #ffffff, 2em -2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 3em 0em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 2em 2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 0em 3em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -2em 2em 0 0em #ffffff, -3em 0em 0 0.2em #ffffff, -2em -2em 0 0em #ffffff;
  }
  87.5% {
    box-shadow: 0em -3em 0em 0em #ffffff, 2em -2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 3em 0em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 2em 2em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, 0em 3em 0 -0.5em #ffffff, -2em 2em 0 0em #ffffff, -3em 0em 0 0em #ffffff, -2em -2em 0 0.2em #ffffff;
  }
}
```

Note how the `keyframes` name is `@name` instead of `spinwhite` what I'd like it to be. According to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974128/how-to-set-keyframes-name-in-less) post, this approach should be working in LESS 1.7.x and up, but according to the [changelog](http://vswebessentials.com/changelog) of Web Essentials, the compiler used in the latest version is version 1.6.3.

Does anyone have an idea of how to get this working? Or is it just gonna be a matter of waiting and be patient and hoping Web Essentials will be updating its compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a working solution, but it feels a bit like a "hack". I've downloaded the latest [LESS-compiler](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/less/less.js/master/dist/less-1.7.3.min.js) and overwritten the one used by Web Essentials, which is found at **C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Extensions\[SOME SEEMINGLY RANDOM CHARACTERS]\Resources\Scripts** with filename **less-1.6.3.min.js**.

For the new compiler to work I did have to use the same filename as the existing compiler. After that it was just a matter of restarting Visual Studio and resaving my LESS-file. The generated CSS-file now contains the code I'd expected and wanted.

Until Web Essentials is updated with the new LESS compiler, this solution will suffice for me.